# Using Bash to write to a device in /sys?

Tags: linux, shell-script, hardware, sysfs

I have one of [these](http://www.dreamcheeky.com/webmail-notifier):

[image]

Basically, it's a USB device with three LEDs (red, green, and blue).

The Linux kernel has supported this device through the `usbled` module for quite some time now. However, I am not sure how to actually control the device from a Bash script. The `/sys` directory contains the following files:

```
root@desktop:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-3/5-3:1.0# ls
bAlternateSetting   bInterfaceSubClass  ep_81     red
bInterfaceClass     blue                green     subsystem
bInterfaceNumber    bNumEndpoints       modalias  supports_autosuspend
bInterfaceProtocol  driver              power     uevent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files `red`, `green`, and `blue` are char devices that allow ASCII decimal values to be written to them.

For example, to change the device to bright red, one would do the following*:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 9 >red
echo 0 >green
echo 0 >blue
```

<sub>* note that this must be run as root</sub>